# Optimisation of recursive knapsack variant

Tags: c++, recursion, knapsack-problem

I have N different items with integer weights and a bag with weight-capacity K.

In the 'normal' knapsack problem the items also have a value and the goal is to find the maximum value of items that can be carried away. Instead I want to find the number of possible combinations of things that can be carried.

My code produces the correct output but is terribly inefficient (for example with 25 items that could all simultaneously fit in the bag there are 33,554,432 function calls). Is there a way to make this process faster?

```
void possibleSets(vector<int> items, int capacity, long int &count)
{   
    // Look at the first item in the list
    int currentItem = items.at(0);

    // If that first item in the list could fit in your bag then +1 count
    if (capacity - currentItem > -1){
        count++;
    }

    if (items.size() == 1){ // No more combinations left to try
        return; 
    }
    else {
        items.erase(items.begin());

        // Recursive call 1:
        // Ignore that first item, and try the rest of the list
        possibleSets(items, capacity, count); 

        // Recursive call 2:
        // Put that first item in your bag, then try the rest of the list
        capacity -= currentItem;
        if (capacity > -1){
            possibleSets(items, capacity, count);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For this kind of problem it doesn't matter much how fast or slow your code is, it won't scale anyway.

Comment: I you want to improve already working code it's probably better to ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could improve your constants a bit.  In particular, this line `items.erase(items.begin())` is pretty expensive for a `vector`.  You could use a `list` or better, modify the code to use iterators.

Comment: Why you give list by value `vector<int> items`, not by reference ? And do it securely, use iterators, indexes, `vector_view`, but not allocate and copy data on every call, this give you huge improvements on big `items.size()`

Comment: The comment by @msandiford (and the other similar suggestion) was very helpful, changing the code to use iterators and pass by reference made a big difference. (Thanks also to the other commenter for telling me about SE code review, which I didn't know about).